# Open Fragment OnClick on Recyclerview item from ApI

Tags: android

I am getting data from API in recycleview using AQuery but now i want to open fragment from API onclick on recyclerview item so how can i implement this.
I want to do same as Instagram app,like on home page when we click on name we get all the details of users on another fragment.

Comment: Simply you can use _FragmentTransaction_. But open fragment from adapter class is not a recommended way so you need to implement listener for that.

Answer (score 3):

```
//CouponFragment.java
public class CouponFragment extends Fragment implements CouponList.OnActionCompleted{
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        recyclerView = new RecyclerView(getActivity());
        return recyclerView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayList<String> coupons = new ArrayList<>();
        coupons.add("Tamil");
        coupons.add("English");
        coupons.add("Malay");
        coupons.add("Chinese");
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new CouponList(coupons,CouponFragment.this));
    }
    @Override
    public void OnClick(Coupon coupon){
        //new fragment
        CouponDetails couponDetails  = new CouponDetails();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.home_container, couponDetails);
        //R.id.home_container  is your FrameLayout id
        transaction.addToBackStack("couponDetails");
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

cardview_coupon_info.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:transitionName="coupon_info_card"
    android:id="@+id/coupon_info_card"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/item_margin"
    card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/coupon_description"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:layout_margin="4dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

CouponList.java (Recyclerview adapter)

```
public class CouponList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CouponList.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> coupons;
    private OnActionCompleted callback;

    public CouponList(ArrayList<String> coupons,OnActionCompleted callback)
    {
        this.coupons = coupons;
        this.callback = callback;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_coupon_info,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.description.setText(coupons.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return coupons.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView description;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.coupon_description);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String coupon = coupons.get(getAdapterPosition());
            callback.OnClick(coupon);
        }

    }

    public interface OnActionCompleted {
        public void OnClick(Coupon coupon);
    }
}
```

You can use this in Activity as well for easy implementation for multiple widget clicks in recycler view item :)

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in your recycler view item onClick.

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();// If you're in an activity.
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();// If you're already inside another fragment
YourFragment yfObj = new YourFragment();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, yfObj).commit();
```

Here, fm is the FragmentManager object, with which only you can conduct a fragment transaction, such as loading a new fragment.

yfObj is the object of the fragment class that you want to load.

R.id.fragmentContainer is the id of the container layout you have declared in your XML file, where you want to load the fragment.

Hope this helps !

Comment: i have to put OnClickListner in RecyclerViewAdapter  or in  MainFragment class?and where to put API in MainFragment?

Comment: You can create the object of the root layout of your recycler view item layout in your adapter and handle the click there.

Comment: And for the API, I'm guessing you can call the API in the activity/fragment and load the data from API there. And then feed that data to the adapter class to load the recycler view.